# Extracting values from HTML

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I am trying to extract values from some html. Here is the the part of the HTML document I am trying to get values from.

```
    <input type="hidden" id="first"
        value='&euro;218.33' />
    <input type="hidden" id="second"
        value='&euro;291.08' />
    <input type="hidden" id="third"
        value='&euro;344.77' />
```

I have used the following preg match all command, where $buffer contains the entire html for the page I am searching.

```
if (preg_match_all('/<input type="hidden" id="(.+?)" value=\'&euro;(.+?)\'/', $buffer, $matches))
{
   echo "FOUND";
   echo  $matches[2][0] . " " . $matches[2][1] . " " . $matches[2][2] . "\n";
}
```

This preg match command is not finding any matches. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is a very easy-to-use HTML paraser for PHP.

Comment: @Adnan SimpleHTMLDom is crapware IMO. Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regexp is not returning anything because there is more than one space between the id and the value...

```
preg_match_all('/<input type="hidden" id="(.+?)"[.\s\t\r\n\v\f]*?value=\'&euro;(.+?)\'/', $buffer, $matches)
```

note the [.\s\t\r\n\v\f]*? just before value=. This will take any characters after the closing " of the id and before the value=". This way spaces, tabs, linebreaks and others will not break your expression.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution is using `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` [str_get_html](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

HTML Example

```
include "simple_html_dom.php" ;

$html =" <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"first\"
    value='&euro;218.33' />
<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"second\"
    value='&euro;291.08' />
<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"third\"
    value='&euro;344.77' />";
```

Usage

```
$html = str_get_html($html);
foreach($html->find('input') as $element)
    echo $element->value . '\n';
```

Output

```
€218.33
€291.08
€344.77
```

Comment: @Gordon Click on str_get_html  it would take you to PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if (preg_match_all('/<input type="hidden" id="(.+?)".+?value=\'&euro;(.+?)\'/s', $buffer, $matches))
```

Comment: Different platforms don't treat . as a newline character. It is safer to specify newline too.

Comment: `s (PCRE_DOTALL)
    If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.` says the manual.